# iCloud Folder Creating and Saving in iOS

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfilemanager

I need to create Folder in `Cloud` and save my `.txt` Text File into that Folder.

So i created folder with following codes in `AppDelegate`

```
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if(ubiq)
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *rootURL = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        NSURL *newFolder = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Notes" relativeToURL:rootURL];

        [fm createDirectoryAtURL:newFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NO Error");
        }
    }
```

After i test it , It show No Error.
So i assumed that it created Notes Folder in iCloud.

However when i save my text document into that folder with following codes , it showing error and not save.

```
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",fileName];

    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage =
    [[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"]
     URLByAppendingPathComponent:file];

    Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];

    [doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }

        else
        {
            doc.noteContent = self.txtView.text;
            [doc updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];
        }
    }];
```

And the error message is

```
Foundation called mkdir("/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/35QNLTQU29~com~myapp~iCloudTest/Documents/Notes/(A Document Being Saved By iCloudTest)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 2.
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I might be wrong, but in you first fragment you create a {iCloud}/Notes folder and in the second you try to write in a {iCloud}/Documents/Notes folder so adjust one or the other